# WooCommerce NON EU VAT message on checkout - changing code to include an array instead of single value

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout

I'm using a modified snippet from BBloomer on my checkout.

I looks for the country selected, and if country is Norway 'NO', it echos a message after the total amount regarding TAX info for Non EU countries.

As we now ship to UK and Switcherland as well, I want tom include those countries in mu script.

That means that the var countryCode = 'NO'; should be something like var countryCode = array( 'NO','UK','CH' ); or ?

Rest of the mighty also need to handle an array instead of the single value.

Hope anybody can help.

```
// The message
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'bbloomer_echo_notice_shipping' );
  
function bbloomer_echo_notice_shipping() {
   echo '<tr class="non-eu-tax-notice" style="display:none">
   <th>'. __( 'Notice', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
   <td data-title=" '. __( 'Notice', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">'. __( 'No VAT charged. Please be aware that VAT and customs can be declared in your home country. More info here', 'woocommerce' ) .'</td>
   </tr>';
}
  

// Show or hide message based on billing country
  
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review', 'bbloomer_show_notice_shipping' );
  
function bbloomer_show_notice_shipping(){
     
   wc_enqueue_js( "
  
      // Set the country code that will display the message
      var countryCode = 'NO';
 
      // Get country code from checkout
      selectedCountry = $('select#billing_country').val();
 
      // Function to toggle message
      function toggle_upsell( selectedCountry ) {   
         if( selectedCountry == countryCode ){
            $('.non-eu-tax-notice').show();
         }
         else {
            $('.non-eu-tax-notice').hide();
         }
      }
 
      // Call function
      toggle_upsell( selectedCountry );
      $('select#billing_country').change(function(){
         toggle_upsell( this.value );         
      });
  
   " );
     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help! :D

I'm the [WooCommerce: Show Message Upon Country Selection @ Checkout](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-show-message-after-state-selection-checkout/) tutorial author.

In jQuery/JS, you can define an array:

```
var countryCode = [ 'NO', 'GB', 'CH' ];
```

Also, you can use a JS equivalent for PHP's in_array() which is inArray() to see if an element is inside the defined list of countries:

```
if ( $.inArray(selectedCountry,countryCode) !== -1 ){
```

Final code:

```
function bbloomer_show_notice_shipping(){
     
   wc_enqueue_js( "
  
      // Set the country code that will display the message
      var countryCode = [ 'NO', 'GB', 'CH' ];
 
      // Get country code from checkout
      selectedCountry = $('select#billing_country').val();
 
      // Function to toggle message
      function toggle_upsell( selectedCountry ) {   
         if ( $.inArray(selectedCountry,countryCode) !== -1 ){
            $('.non-eu-tax-notice').show();
         }
         else {
            $('.non-eu-tax-notice').hide();
         }
      }
 
      // Call function
      toggle_upsell( selectedCountry );
      $('select#billing_country').change(function(){
         toggle_upsell( this.value );         
      });
  
   " );
     
}
```